# How do I solve the SQL(query) missing database error?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                     Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                         (near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM notesWHEREid='1')

This is the error i am getting:

This is the part of my database handler that is the source of this error:

```
    public void deleteNote(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String deleteQuery="DELETE FROM " + DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES + "WHERE" + DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID + "= '" + id + "'";

    db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: And what is the query right before you execute it? Please learn to debug your code. You won't get far without knowing how to do it.

Comment: @juergend Truer words have not been spoken!!! :)

Comment: Look into using parameters as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# 6.0, using interpolated strings makes life much easier for strings concatenation, avoiding such silly errors:

```
String deleteQuery= $"DELETE FROM {DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES} WHERE {DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID} = id";
```

**Note**: $ operator is available in C# 6.0. Also you should take a look into [how to build parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662999/system-data-sqlite-parameterized-queries-with-multiple-values) because passing parameters like this can expose you to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - yes, I know. That's why I have put the link for parameterized queries.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - this is not entirely true, as some people managed to make it work in earlier versions of Visual studio ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)) or even without Visual Studio ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)).

Answer (score 1):

Change your following statement:

```
String deleteQuery="DELETE FROM " + DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES + "WHERE" + DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID + "= '" + id + "'";
```

to

```
String deleteQuery= "DELETE FROM " + DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES + " WHERE " + DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID + " = '" + id + "'";
```

Actually you are combining the table name with where clause. You need to add a space before and after WHERE Clause like  " Where "

Hope it helps.